# restricted shell for backup

Tags: shell, security, backup

I was thinking about creating some backup solution for my NAS. My idea is that I could set up a remote system with ssh access and backup tool (whichever I choose to use) would upload files there. All fine, but what happens if my main system is hacked and attacker gets access to all system resources, including access to my backup system. This will allow the attacker to delete backup files stored there.

Therefore I was thinking that the remote system could have an access set up the way that files could not be deleted using the account that uploads the files (backup software).

Is there anything like this available? I guess it could be an scp compatible shell that does not allow deletes (at least after some sort of commit). Another idea is a remote's system server side script that would copy the protected files to a location outside of reach for the access account (but this requires additional storage space unless something like vdo is used).

Comment: it is possible with FTP, though this induce a special issue being that you will end with infinite retention on your destination backup storage and you will have to handle retention policy from there making the backup complicated to manage.

Comment: An alternative is to have the backup system *pull* files from your NAS and other systems using something like NDMP. Enterprises use this to backup potentially insecure desktop systems. The backup system is not on the Internet and you don't login to it from insecure systems.